# jquery functions to add rows to two different HTML tables

Tags: jquery, html

I have two HTML tables with different Table IDs and when I add rows to my tables they always get added to the 'leaderboard' table.  How can i distinguish that the function leaderSuccess should write to the 'leaderboard' table and function titalSucess should write to the 'titaltown' table?

```
============JQUERY===========
 function leaderSuccess(results) {
    var numItemsRead = results.length;
    var $tableBody = $('<tbody></tbody>');           
    for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
        var leaderboard = results[i];
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>');                     
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(leaderboard.owner)); 
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(leaderboard.points));
        $tableBody.append($row);                     

    }

    $('thead').after($tableBody);                    


}



function titalSuccess(results) {
    var numItemsRead = results.length;     
    var $tableBody = $('<tbody></tbody>');           
    for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
        var titals = results[i];
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>');                     
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(titals.owner));
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(titals.titals));
        $tableBody.append($row);                     
    }

    $('thead').after($tableBody);                    



=========HTML============
<table id="leaderboard">
    <thead><tr><th>Owner</th><th>Points</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
 </table>  

<table id="titletown">
    <thead><tr><th>Owner</th><th>Titals</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>     

function leaderEventHandler(event) {
        leaderBoard
            .orderByDescending('points')
            .read()
            .then(leaderSuccess, failure);
}

function titalEventHandler(event) {
        titals
            .orderByDescending('titals')
            .read()
            .then(titalSuccess, failure);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any event associated with the tables which invokes the respective functions. What triggers those functions ?

Comment: Why are you writing in `tbody` elements that already exist? Can't simply append the rows?

Comment: @isherwood that's a good question, wasn't sure if it was done on purpose or not, would be more convenient to change the contents of existing <tbody> or delete it from html section

Comment: it was done on purpose, mostly because most of the code works! Just need a way to distinguish between the leaderboard table and titaltown table...

Comment: Try to console.log(results); first thing inside titalSuccess() function and see if there's any data

Comment: yea, a whole bunch of object object references....I do in fact know there is good data because it was adding rows to the leaderboard table in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the ID when appending html to a table

```
 function leaderSuccess(results) {
    var numItemsRead = results.length;
    var $tableBody = $('<tbody></tbody>');           
    for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
        var leaderboard = results[i];
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>');                     
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(leaderboard.owner)); 
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(leaderboard.points));
        $tableBody.append($row);                     

    }

    $('#leaderboard thead').after($tableBody); // append to id="leaderboard" table                  

}

function titalSuccess(results) {
    var numItemsRead = results.length;     
    var $tableBody = $('<tbody></tbody>');           
    for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
        var titals = results[i];
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>');                     
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(titals.owner));
        $row.append($('<td></td>').text(titals.titals));
        $tableBody.append($row);                     
    }

    $('#titletown thead').after($tableBody); // append to id="titletown" table                                      
}
```

Comment: This looked good, i thought anyways. the leaderboard table looks good, but titaltown table is empty..

Comment: You gotta include the code where you execute those functions

Comment: i added the two calling functions to my original post. function leaderEventHandler and titalEventHandler

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where those functions are being called, but you could pass an ID as second argument:

```
function leaderSuccess(results, tableId) { 
    ... 
    $('#' + tableId).find('tbody').append( ... );
}
```

Comment: having trouble formatting my code to make it look readable in the comments, but the calls to each function are coming from another function on a click event where a table is read and passed to leaderSuccess or titalSuccess depending on which click took place